# I want to change the background color on my blog posts

Tags: css, blog

I am using the css body { backgroundcolor: black } and it colours all pages, but only want to colour my posts. I have tried body .post { backgroundcolor: black } but it colours the container instead.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating your own theme? Or are you editing an existing theme? In either of the cases, I would advise you to learn more about [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and to learn how to use  [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css) to inspect and change your CSS

Comment: It's and existing one. I just need to know how to change that one thing.

Comment: Right-click on the element you want to change, and go to Inspect -> Elements, there you will need to find the markup for the element you wish to change and see if it has any custom classes or IDs, read up on Selectors and Chrome Dev Tools, it will help you out and it never hurts to learn something new